# Google Maps API v3 street address vs city, zip

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3 Distance.  It has worked well for the majority of the addresses in my database.  However, it seems like some addresses just aren't available in Google Maps, and it seems to pick the closest street address match which could be way off.  I would expect Google Maps in this case to provide an answer based on city and zip.  Does anyone have a solution?  I've thought of double checking mathematically by geocode and checking Yahoo maps(or other sites) for the ones that are way off but that adds processing time and is not a very elegant solution.  There must be some setting I'm missing or other such work around.

Thanks!

BTW shout out to the new Json Serializer!  Well it was new to me anyways.

Answer (score 0):

How are you formatting the address you are sending ?

I've used the Google Maps API to do some reverse geocoding and if a street could not be found (due to a typo or what have you) Google would return the lat lng for the historic town center.

I structured addresses as Country, city cityzip, street nr.

Comment: Hi, the formatted web request is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=###+ABC+ABC+ROAD+ABC+AA+#####&destination=###+ABC+ABC+ROAD+ABC+AA+#####&&mode=driving&units=imperial&region=us&sensor=false thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `location_type` of the `geometr`y object to determine what accuracy was returned.  I suggest checking to see if the returned resulsts indicate whether a result is anything other than `ROOFTOP` or `RANGE_INTERPOLATED`.